# how to set a variable such that it can be accessed any where in my ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible, devops

here is my playbook main.yml. I want to use the playbook_name variable in the import_playbook module. But I am not able to access it. Is there any way i can access this variable?

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: Get playbook_name 
    shell: <command>
    register: playbook_name
    ignore_errors: yes
    become: yes

  - debug: var=hostvars['localhost']['playbook_name']
    ignore_errors: True
    
- name: Include playbook based on playbook_name
  import_playbook: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['playbook_name']['response'] }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend starting a new file under your inventories, like `inventory/internal_vars`, and then putting your variable in there. Then, you can import that file as variables using the `vars_files` module in your `main.yml` playbook like so:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars_files:
    - inventory/internal_vars
  tasks:
  - name: Get playbook_name 
    shell: <command>
    register: playbook_name
    ignore_errors: yes
    become: yes
```

Note: The path to the file has to be a relative path from your playbook to the inventory/internal_vars file. The code above assumes the playbook and inventory folder are in the base level folder.

Reference: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-in-included-files-and-roles